# SUM on multiple dynamic criteria on a separate sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, lambda, sum, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to write a formula that will sum values across multiple rows from a separate sheet based on multiple criteria. If it helps with context, the report will be a cashflow statement that sums up the different account types and displays them together on a dashboard. Here is a copy of the workbook I am using:

[published](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ2oBYbsebh-ilqyBthl4RhOHSz7uipjwBkzzHlJRP3ceK6AyZ7YsOSWpFJjAVGS0IIFH-keP7uQN7Q/pubhtml)                or
[shareable](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1doP8Dv6UNalKvBFxNP0gFuq5tzVNYCAcs2jLzkkV34U/edit?usp=sharing)

For example, in the linked workbook, for Cell B9 on the Dashboard sheet I want to sum all of the Credit Card - Credit Card values for the month of Sep 2022 from Practice A.

I've been able to write a formula that will return only the first value it finds for the criteria, not a sum of all the values. Here is what I currently have in B9:

```
=IFNA(SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT(B$3&"!$A$10:$ZZZ"),MATCH($A9,INDIRECT(B$3&"!$B$10:$B"),0),MATCH(DATEVALUE($F$1),DATEVALUE(INDIRECT(B$3&"!$9:$9")),0))))
```

It returns the first value for those criteria (-$33,863.01) on the Practice A sheet for Sep 2022 rather than the sum of all rows matching the criteria (-$51,261.69) on the Practice A sheet for Sep 2022.

Any and all help / feedback is appreciated!

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Thanks @player0 all of the formulas worked perfectly. I think I'll stick to the sum with indirects because I can at least understand the functions! Unless there is an optimization / efficiency reason why the others may be more beneficial?

Comment: it's up to individual preference but in general, fewer formulae per spreadsheet = higher performance so according to that the last fx is the most efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formula is:

```
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER('Practice A'!C10:Z, 'Practice A'!C9:Z9*1=
 EOMONTH(F1, -1)+1), 'Practice A'!B10:B=A9))
```

with indirects:

```
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(INDIRECT(B3&"!C10:Z"), INDIRECT(B3&"!C9:Z9")*1=
 EOMONTH(F1, -1)+1), INDIRECT(B3&"!B10:B")=A9))
```

[image]

with some tweaking it could be written as:

```
=LAMBDA(x, SUM(FILTER(FILTER(OFFSET(x,,,9^9, 24), OFFSET(x, -1,,,24)*1=
 EOMONTH($F1, -1)+1), OFFSET(x,,-1, 9^9)=$A9)))(INDIRECT(B3&"!C10"))
```

[image]

or even arrayformula like:

```
=BYCOL(B3:F3, LAMBDA(y, LAMBDA(x, SUM(FILTER(FILTER(OFFSET(x,,,9^9, 24), OFFSET(x, -1,,,24)*1=
 EOMONTH($F1, -1)+1), OFFSET(x,,-1, 9^9)=$A9)))(INDIRECT(y&"!C10"))))
```

[image]